# aurioTouch example project is not correct for iOS 5

Tags: ios5, audio

I use iPhone aurioTouch project from site *.apple.com.
The aurioTouch reads data from microphone and etc. Also it uses sound effects there. 
It runs correctly on iOs 3.x and iOs 4.x.

But in iOS 5.0  all sounds are gone.
The App keeps the silence.

Does anybody know how to fix this bug?

Thanks

Vadim